# Create keyboard shortcut for automatic source formatting in workbench

Tags: keyboard, workbench

In the context menu under *Source* there is an option to automatically format/indent code, but it doesn't have a keybinding associated.

The command also doesn't seem to appear in the *Window → Preferences → General → Keys* menu.

[image: Keybinding menu]

I tried editing the plugin.xml file in `eclipse/plugins/com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET_10.1.757` as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F), but to no avail. I'm not even sure whether that is the correct file to edit and which command id to use.

Comment: Have you work out how to add the keybinding of format?